# Setting alpha of background of layout using setAlpha doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, alpha, android-seekbar

I am a bit confused.
I have this :

```
this.opacitySeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            // updating opacity of layout
            RelativeLayout ledColor;
            for(int index = 0; index < selectedLedsIndices.size(); index++) {
                ledColor = (RelativeLayout)ledsLayout.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.led_color);
                ledColor.setAlpha(((float)i) / 255); 
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

I am trying to change the opacity of a layout using the progress value of a seekbar. The value of the seekbar goes from à to 255. But when running, the opacity of the layout doesn't change. I'm getting no error trace. It just doesn't want to change. How that?

I am running the app on api 24 (and my app should target api from 19 to 27).

Comment: What is  `ledsLayout` and what is `ledColor`? Post your xml and make clear which layout you want to change its alpha and how you access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ledColor.getBackground().setAlpha(...)`

Comment: it still doesn't work...........I am working inside a fragment, but it shouldn't be a problem...I really don't see where is the problem.